# In usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Which of the following metric spaces X is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For $X ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$, consider $X$ as a metric space with metric induced by the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Which of the following metric spaces X
is complete?

$A. X = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{ Z} \subset \mathbb{ R} \times \mathbb{R}$

$B. X = \mathbb{Q } \times \mathbb{ R} \subset \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$

$C.$ $X = (−π, π) \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$

$D.$ $X = [−π, π] \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) ⊂ \mathbb{R}$

I thinks  option A,B and  C will be correct As both  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$   are complete

Is  its correct ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb Q$ is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $\mathbb Q$ is *not* complete and answer B. is wrong. Only answer A. is correct. I hope that you know how to justify that.

Comment: In a complete metric space the only complete subspaces ( in the inherited metric) are the closed ones. Only A is closed in the ambient space.

Comment: Yes. that's what the OP should use to justify that A. is the only correct option, but I did not want to tell that to her.